# IFSTREAM and OFSTREAM not saving info correctly

Tags: visual-c++, configuration, ifstream, ofstream

I would like to allow my application to use configuration files. The problem I am having is that IFSTREAM and OFSTREAM append the data in a way that it can't be deciphered.

How can I use an operator like "|" instead so the IFSTREAM can know it is starting a new value? I have 10 integers and one string to store.

Here are my functions:

```
int readConf() {
    ifstream fin("C:\\share\\conf2.xyz");
    if (fin.is_open()) {
        fin >> hueSlider;
        fin >> hueSlider2;
        fin >> satSlider;
        fin >> satSlider2;
        fin >> valSlider;
        fin >> valSlider2;
        fin >> accuracy;
        fin >> dilateIterations;
        fin >> CAPTYPE;
        fin >> CAPDEV;
        fin >> uri;
        fin.close();
        return 0;
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
}

int writeConf() {
    ifstream fout("C:\\share\\conf2.xyz");
    fout << hueSlider;
    fout << hueSlider2;
    fout << satSlider;
    fout << satSlider2;
    fout << valSlider;
    fout << valSlider2;
    fout << accuracy;
    fout << dilateIterations;
    fout << CAPTYPE;
    fout << CAPDEV;
    fout << uri;
    fout.close();
    cout << "\n$\tConfiguration Written!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Here's what the file holds:
0255025501473100http://10.11.65.11/mjpg/video.mjpg

Comment: Append std::endl.  Or use binary mode.

Comment: so that worked on the ofstream, but how do I separate the valus in ifstream?

Comment: Never Mind, i just added those to the OFSTREAM and now the IFSTREAM can read/write with no error! Thank you!